# Why I can't add timestamp value to my timestamp field in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in mysql database and when I do an update on it like this:

```
UPDATE `texts` SET `start_time` = '1444562855' WHERE `texts`.`text_id` = 529;
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Modified records: 0
Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column 'start_time' at row 1
```

The field start_time has a type `TIMESTAMP` and I have another timestamp field in this table, however I've read that it's possible to store two timestamps in one table if the MySQL verion is higher than 5.6.+ (my version is `5.6.26`).

What it doesn't work?

I don't want to change the type of this field to datetime since my backend logic is supporting timestamps only.. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [FROM_UNIXTIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) and remove the quotes :

```
UPDATE `texts` SET `start_time` = FROM_UNIXTIME(1444562855) WHERE `texts`.`text_id` = 529;
```

Comment: thanks! and what about the query in php when I have it like this:

`$create = $conn2->prepare("INSERT INTO texts(`User_id`, `start_time`) VALUES (:client_id, :played_date)");
 $create->bindParam(':client_id', $Client_id);
 $create->bindParam(':played_date', $date_to_db);` now it still puts only zeros instead of timestamp.. How should I modify it?

Comment: $create = $conn2->prepare("INSERT INTO texts(User_id, start_time) VALUES (:client_id, FROM_UNIXTIME (:played_date))"); should works and be sure $date_to_db is an integer